In NextJs, the page is not reloading even when the params are changed. How to reload page when params are changed?
I am currently on http://localhost:3000/?groupId=chicago&dayOfWeek=tuesday and when I press a button on a component, it should take me to another day, like thursday. However, it's not happening
import { useRouter, usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

const SelectDayDialog = ({ groupId, organization }) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const thursday = "Thursday"; 

    const handleGroupSelection = (dayOfWeek) => {
        const query = { groupId: groupId, dayOfWeek: dayOfWeek.toLowerCase() }; 
        const queryString = new URLSearchParams(query).toString();

        let routeUrl = `/?${queryString}`;

        router.push(routeUrl);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleGroupSelection(thursday)}>Thursday</button>
        </div>
    );
};

When I press the button, the url is changing to http://localhost:3000/?groupId=chicago&dayOfWeek=thursday. However, there is no change in the page and the components/content is not updating.
How do I fix this?

// page.tsx (server component)
interface PropsTableScompra {
    searchParams: {
        [key: string]: string | undefined;
    };
}

async function MovimientosPage({ searchParams }: PropsTableScompra) {

   
    const groupId = searchParams?.groupId || '';
    const dayOfWeek = searchParams?.dayOfWeek || '';

    // client component
    <SelectDayDialog  groupId={groupId} dayOfWeek={dayOfWeek} />
......

in client component use reouter.replace

remember type "use client" in the top code client component because uses event onChange ....
